# Using AWK to get text and looping in csv

Tags: csv, awk

i'am new in awk and i want ask...
i have a csv file like this

```
IVALSTART  IVALEND   IVALDATE
23:00:00   23:30:00  4/9/2012

STATUS  LSN      LOC
K       lskpg    1201
K       lntrjkt  1201
K       lbkkstp  1211
```

and i want to change like this

```
IVALSTART  IVALEND
23:00:00   23:30:00

STATUS  LSN      LOC   IVALDATE
    K   lskpg    1201   4/9/2012
    K   lntrjkt  1201   4/9/2012
    K   lbkkstp  1211   4/9/2012
```

How to do it in awk?

thanks and best regards!

Comment: I wouldn't call that a csv file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk '
NR == 1 { name = $3; print $1, $2 }
NR == 2 { date = $3; print $1, $2 }
NR == 3 { print "" }
NR == 4 { $4 = name; print } 
NR >  4 { $4 = date; print }
' FILE
```

If you need formating, it's necessary to change `print` to `printf` with appropriate specifiers.